# SOQL on ContentVersion results in 'invalid parameter value'

Tags: soql, rest-api, contentversion

I am writing a query to upload the contentversions which are not present in my Organization. For this, I am checking the presence of contentversion if it exists or not. This hit a snag where the query:

```
SELECT ID FROM CONTENTVERSION WHERE ID IN ('068c0000000FYd5AAL')
```

fails with 'Invalid parameter value' if this particular Id is not present. If it is present, the corresponding Id is returned. 
A strange behaviour is that if an Id is not present in the list of Ids, the error is returned.

I wouldn't want to test by running query against every id on my side as it would be a waste of API Calls. Is there a way that I can make it certain that the ContentVersion that is being uploaded doesn't exist already?

Comment: can not offer anything other then trying short id format or trying to access the object by id in browser /068c0000000FYd5AAL, which could give some more details why the id is considered invalid.

Comment: Thanks. But the program written is on the backend and resides on API calls. Besides, it is obvious that I cannot check whether this Id is present in the org individually for the above mentioned reason.

Comment: Why not upsert?

Comment: I'm puzzled by the requirement -- one `ContentDocument` has multiple `ContentVersions`. What is the starting condition in the database versus the input data set?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Upsert caused issue while some items were in recycle bin. In addition to this, upserting all the fields were of an issue. For example, some fields are updateable, createable, etc. If it is either one, I have to include the relevant fields. Using upsert on a field that is createable or updateable only threw errors.Hence this tortuous method of querying the ids.

Comment: @cropredy This is a generic case where the database backup contains the records for any objectthat has to be uploaded to the org. Tried inserting a few objects such as account, contact, documents and it worked. Stumped with this object and might be a few objects down the way. Instead of the id field, should contentdocumentid field should be used? It threw the same error if that particular contentdocumentid is not present. There's no create on contentdocument. Should this default to creating a new contentversion? However, determining the presence of contentdocumentid seems to be the issue here.

Comment: Sfdc creates a ContentDocument for the first time a ContentVersion is inserted.  Querying the newly created ContentVersion allows you to discover the ContentDocumentId